# Constant reference parameter causing unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, reference, constants, unresolved-external, const-reference

Below is a simplified version of some code I wrote. this code works fine so far

class.h

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    class myClass
    {
    public:

        myClass(unsigned width, unsigned height);
        myClass(OtherClass& other, unsigned width, unsigned height);
        ~myClass(){};

    private:
        unsigned width;
        unsigned height;
    };
}
```

class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

namespace myNamespace
{
    myClass::myClass(unsigned width, unsigned height)
    {
        //code
    }

    myClass::myClass(OtherClass& other, unsigned width, unsigned height) : myClass(width, height)
    {
        //code  
    }
}
```

(OtherClass is defined elsewhere inside the myNamespace and is included)

the constructor that uses OtherClass doesn't alter other so making it const would be appropriate.

But when I change the constructor in both the .cpp and .h to use `const OtherClass&` it gives me the error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall
>   myNamespace::myClass::myClass(class myNamespace::OtherClass &,unsigned
>   int,unsigned int)"
>   (??0CarbonMatrix@molecule@@QAE@AAVCarbonString@1@II@Z) referenced in
>   function _wmain   path\main.obj

As far as I know const shouldn't cause this error as long you use them both at the declaration and at the definition.

So my question: What goes wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Whats your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates, that you have actually not changed the declaration in the header file or did not recompile all source files after changing it.

Double check that you indeed changed it to `const OtherClass&` in the header file. Then re-compile the *whole* project, i.e. not only class.cpp, but also main.cpp.

Comment: I double checked. It wouldn't even let me compile if i wouldn't have it the same at both sides. So I'm sure it has the same parameters.
I'm not really sure if i compile the whole project. i use VS 2013 and just press Local Windows Debugger.